# what is "-" means in distance field of chrome memory devtool

Tags: javascript, memory, garbage-collection, google-chrome-devtools

[image]

after click on garbege collect button the object shows "-" for the distance column, is this means the object is not reachable and it is garbage collected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be incorrect but as per my understanding and experience, "-" means that the object is not reachable but it is not garbage collected due to debug mode. You don't need to worry about it as it will be cleared in production mode.

To confirm that, you can expand your object in memory heap and see if the object is hold by DebugContext_. Refer the screenshot attached.
[Memory Heap of an object with Distance '-'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuAdM.png)

To see the memory heap without obfuscation, you need to enable production mode. In case of an Angular CLI, you can enable the production mode by modifying the below code in main.ts file of your project:

```
if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}
```